# Debian 6.0.7, allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include in php.ini set, but still can't include remote files?

Tags: php, apache, include, debian

I know the security implications of what I'm trying to do, so don't worry about that, I'm doing a small LFI/RFI demo on a small VPS I own, and the page itself is passworded out via .htaccess.

I've set both

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

in php.ini, but when including files I get just a blank page. Php filters don't work either, same blank page. Files from inside the filesystem work fine.

What's interesting, in the logs nothing at all is shown, except complaining about a missing favicon (I'm looking at /var/log/apache2/error.log, and I'm using /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for the config).

The code looks like this:

```
<?php $page = $_GET['page'];
if ($page=="") echo "blank page"; else {include($page);} ?>
```

Which is pretty simple, no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas regarding what might be the problem?

EDIT: 
This works fine:

```
echo(file_get_contents('http://google.com'));
```

This doesn't:

```
include('http://google.com');
```

Comment: your getting the text "blank page" or your getting a blank page? :)

Comment: The place where the file should go is blank,text around shows up :)

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me, too. I was able to fix it by disabling the suhosin plugin.